# Material Design for Angular 2 throws ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to get Material Design for Angular2 (https://github.com/angular/material2) to work with my project.

After running:

```
npm install --save @angular/material
npm start
```

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

Here is my npm-debug.log:
http://pastebin.com/raw/GCffjQMh

Comment: Exact same thing happened to me with Node v6.10.1, npm v3.10.10 and angular/material v2.0.0-beta.5. I used the angular2 quickstart. I am on Windows 10.

Comment: I uninstalled material and I still get the error. I ran a diff on my backup (the only difference being the install then uninstall of material) and other than the order of some dependencies in package.json, they are identical. Then I tried starting the backed up project and it is no longer working either.